# Model driven forms - Validators issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-cli

I am testing a simple app. These are my files:

`home.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            'firstName': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            'password': new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(5))
        });
    }
    onSubmit() {
        console.log('model-based form submitted');
        console.log(this.form);
    }
}
```

And this is the template file:

```
<section class="sample-app-content">
    <h1>Model-based Form Example:</h1>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-field">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
        </div>
   <div class="form-field">
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="password">
   </div>
    <p>
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

But it is not recognizing the `Validators` well, because when I write the `firstname` it enables the submit button, then if I put the firstname in blank, the input never change to red.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I created a demo here

http://plnkr.co/edit/cs6N0n?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angular validator sets the `ng-invalid` css class if the validation fails. However you haven't defined `ng-invalid` in your CSS, so you don't get a red border.

If you define the style in the CSS it works:

```
.ng-invalid {
  border-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Don't exactly know why the minLength(5) validator for the password allows an empty password. Either it's an angular bug or intended behavior and you need to combine it with the required validator.

Comment: So let me see if I understood. The validators can only change the state valid of the form and not its behaviour? I supposed there were ng classes working on it. So, if I want to change the colors or display messages I have to add ng directives? i.e: `[class] = "_isvalidform? class-ok: class-notok`?

Comment: No, you don't have to, angular adds and removes the `ng-invalid` class automatically. But you have to define how ng-invalid should be rendered. The browser doesn't know by default that this thing exists and should be red. And angular doesn't bring default css with itself.

Comment: If you want you could however also add similar behavior yourself with `[ngClass.notvalid]`="!form.valid" and define a css for notvalid instead for ng-invalid.